# How restore mongo datebase into new datebase name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, mongorestore

I have a database with name `prod`. I want to restore it to the database with new name `dev`.
Both bases are absent before restoring

the following not working:

```
--archive=/data/db/prod.tar --nsFrom=prod --nsTo=dev

 --db "dev" --archive=/data/db/prod.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

To restoring archive to new datebase with new name:

```
--archive="/data/db/prod.tar" --nsFrom="prod.*" --nsTo="dev.*"
```